# Why does my regex appear to be greedy even when I ask it to be lazy?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am using Ruby 2.1.

My string is `"Here's my user profile (http://example.com/user/5316), it's good. :)"`

I want to capture just the URL in parentheses.

My first effort is `/(http:\/\/example.com.*)\)/`. example.com, and then any character, ending when a closing parentheses is encountered. But nope, that doesn't work. Maybe it's being greedy, I think, and being lazy would help. But appending the laziness operator doesn't help. I try using `[)]` instead of `\)`, but that doesn't help either. I'm kind of stumped.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What "laziness operator" are you using? `/(http:\/\/example.com.*?)\)/` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

The lazy operator works fine:

```
irb> m = "Here's my user profile (http://example.com/user/5316), it's good. :)".match(/(http:\/\/example.com.*?)\)/)
=> #<MatchData "http://example.com/user/5316)" 1:"http://example.com/user/5316">
irb> m[1]
=> "http://example.com/user/5316"
```

The regex should be `/(http:\/\/example.com.*?)\)/` - the lazy operator is the inclusion of the `?`

Comment: thanks for this reply. It does work in your example, unfortunately I didn't provide enough context in my post. The URL isn't always in parentheses. It could be `my user profile at http://example.com/user/600` too, so I can't *rely on* the parentheses being there.

Comment: You should update the question to highlight this. So how will you determine the end of the URL then? Even the other answer requires an end point to the capture pattern. Can the URL contain spaces?

Comment: Yeah, I'll update the post. I suppose the URL would be terminated by any non-URL-legal character, like a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
require "uri"

str = "Here's my user profile (http://example.com/user/5316), it's good. :)"
p URI.extract(str)
```

Comment: This picks up the parenthesis *and* the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negated character class like `[^\s)]*` which matches any character but not of a space or `)`, zero or more times.

```
> "Here's my user profile (http://example.com/user/420), it's good. :)".match(/\bhttp:\/\/example\.com\b[^\s)]*/)[0]
=> "http://example.com/user/420"
```